# ASP.NET MVC, jQuery, modals and complex type list in viewmodel.

Tags: c#, jquery

I have form in add.cshtml. 
I'am using razor and @Html.EditFor() helper.

My viewModel:

```
  public class MerchantViewModel {
  // properties
   public IEnumerable<AddBrandViewModel> Brands { get; set; }
  }

  public class AddBrandViewModel {

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Logo { get; set; }   
    public AddressViewModel Address { get; set; }

  }
```

And now in View I want to create AddMerchantViewModel and sens via ajax to my WebAPI.

I'am using .cshtml pages and @Html.EditFor helper. 
So Brands are collection of AddBrandViewModel.

I need display EditFor(brand => brand) // properties in MODAL. 
And after filled modal I want to add these data to UL in my form. 
How I can display EditFor(brand) in Modal.

Comment: I'd suggest creating custom front-end implementation for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I like to resolve this cases by doing it with a `foreach` loop.

The trick here is to place a name like it was an array.

Example:

```
<div>
    @{
        int idx = 0;
    }

    @foreach (var brand in Model.Brands)
    {
        @Html.TextBox("Brands[" + idx + "].Name", brand.Name);
        @Html.TextBox("Brands[" + idx + "].Url", brand.Url);
        @Html.TextBox("Brands[" + idx + "].Address.PostCode", brand.Address.PostCode);
        @Html.TextBox("Brands[" + idx + "].Address.Locality", brand.Address.Locality);

        idx++;
    }
</div>
```

This way you are sending the properties to be binded like an array.

PS: All the items need to be in order, there mustn't be any jump between idx, like `[1, 3, 4, 5]`, in this case it would only pass to the action `[1]`

Comment: I think I don't understand it. In your code you iterate over brands(collection) and displaying they property. But it's a empty collection because this scenario is in CREATE view.